# How to right-justify URLs inside a table?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable, urls

I have a table containing a URL, and I want the URL to break so that the URL is right-justified along with the other text.

In my example below you can see that the last few lines are not right-justified:

http://www.andrewinfosec.com/latex_1.jpg

I have tried to use `\UrlBreaks` to allow wrapping to occur using any character (see my code below), but this does not work.

Frankly, having the code be `\raggedright` would probably also be okay for my needs, but when I add `\raggedright` I get a bizarre linebreak inserted before the URL:

http://www.andrewinfosec.com/latex_2.jpg

Any help to fix either scenario would be gratefully received!

Here's the code for the first example above:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z\do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\/\do\-\do\_\do\:\do\.}

\begin{document}
\small

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{9.45cm}}

Craig Timberg, Jia Lynn Yang, and Hayley Tsukayama, ``Target says 40 million credit, debit cards may have been compromised in security breach'', \emph{The Washington Post}, December 19, 2013, available: \emph{\url{http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/technology/target-data-breach-affects-40-million-accounts-payment-info-compromised/2013/12/19/5cc71f22-68b1-11e3-ae56-22de072140a2_story.html}}. \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I believe, that the line-breaking for URLS does not differ from regular `tabular` environments and `longtable` environments (except from urls spanning over pages, but that is probably not the case)

Comment: Hi! I'm using longtable because in my real document the table spans multiple pages, so it carried over to my example here.